# Search value from more xml attributes

Tags: c#, xml, search

I have xml e.g.:

```
<text>
...
  <word id="1">this</word>
  <word id="2">is</word>
  <word id="3">sample</word>
  <word id="4">other</word>
  <word id="5">words</word>
...
</text>
```

How is the easiest way to find "this is sample", and get the id from the first word (1)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get you started with a programmatic solution: split your search string

```
var strings = searchString.Split(' ');
```

set a counter to 0 and begin to loop over all the  nodes. If you have a match with strings[counter], increase the counter, otherwise reset it to 0.

Now take it from here.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a school assignment, anyway, something like this may get you going:

```
public string GetIDValue(XDocument xDoc)
{
    foreach (var element in xDoc.Root.Elements("word"))
    {
        if (element.Value == "this")
        {   
            return element.Attribute("id").Value;
        }
    }
}
```

NOTE: I haven't tested this...

Answer (score 0):

This works definitely in the way you want:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    String sampleXml =
    @"<text><word id='1'>this</word>
            <word id='2'>is</word>
            <word id='3'>sample</word>
            <word id='4'>other</word>
            <word id='5'>words</word>
        </text>";
    XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDocument.LoadXml(sampleXml);
    XmlNodeList nodeList = xmlDocument.SelectNodes("text/word");
    foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(node.FirstChild.Value);
    }
    Console.WriteLine(nodeList[0].Attributes["id"].Value);
}
```